# Archive.php filter by custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in the function.php which I create a list of the months which have created post as follows:

2015 Nov Dec

2014 Oct Nov Dec

" Nov " " dec " are link that shows me the url: www.xxx.com/2015/11 post that date.

This using archive.php

The question is : how could do this yourself but by filtering these custom post type link ??

```
function twentyeleven_get_archives_callback($item, $index, $currYear) {
    global $wp_locale;

    if ( $item['year'] == $currYear ) {
        $url = get_month_link( $item['year'], $item['month'] );
        // translators: 1: month name, 2: 4-digit year
        $text = sprintf(__('%1$s %2$d'), $wp_locale->get_month($item['month']), $item['year']);
        $text = substr($text,0,3);
        echo get_archives_link($url, $text);
    }
}

    function twentyeleven_get_archives() {
            global $wpdb;

            $query = "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS `year` FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `post_type` = 'post' AND `post_status` = 'publish' GROUP BY `year` ORDER BY `year` DESC limit 4";
            $arcresults = $wpdb->get_results($query);
            $years = array();

            if ($arcresults) {
                foreach ( (array)$arcresults as $arcresult ) {
                    array_push($years, $arcresult->year);
                }
            }

            $query = "SELECT YEAR(post_date) as `year`, MONTH(post_date) as `month` FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `post_type` = 'post' AND `post_status` = 'publish' GROUP BY `year`, `month` ORDER BY `year` DESC, `month` ASC";
            $arcresults = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
            $months = array();

            if ( $arcresults ) {
                foreach ($years as $year) {
                            //My Display
                    //echo "\t<li>\n\t\t<a href=\"#\">$year</a>\n\t\t<ul>\n";
                    //array_walk($arcresults, "twentyeleven_get_archives_callback", $year);
                    //echo "\t\t</ul>\n\t</li>\n";

                            //Your Display
                    echo "\t<div class='listYearArchive'><span class='yearArchive'>$year</span>\n\t<ul class='listMonthArchive'>\n";
                    array_walk($arcresults, "twentyeleven_get_archives_callback", $year);
                    echo "\t</ul></div>\n";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the post_type right in the query

```
FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `post_type` = 'post'
```

Just change `post` for your custom post name.